# Sufficient condition for optimal control with functional having second order state derivatives

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, constraints

I have been searching for a Theorem which gives sufficient conditions for optimal control problem with state constraints in which the functional has second order state derivates, i.e., the cost function is of the form $$ J = \int_0^1 F(x(t),\dot x(t),\ddot x(t),u(t),t) dt.$$
The problem which I am dealing with has cost function $$ J = \int_0^1 (\ddot x^2 +\ddot y^2) dt ,$$ system dynamics $$\dot x=vcos(\theta), $$$$\dot y=vsin(\theta), $$ where $(x,y)$ is position of the object, $v,\theta$ are the two controls where $v$ is constant speed and $\theta(t)$ is the variable angle(direction) and constraints of the form $$ (x(t)-0.4)^2+(y(t)-0.5)^2 \geq 0.1, $$ $$ (x(t)-0.8)^2+(y(t)-1.5)^2 \geq 0.1. $$ The object is starting at the origin and final point is say $(1.2,1.6)$ at $t=1$.
Can anyone please point me to any material related to this ?

Comment: More context is needed here. What is the dynamics of your system? What are your state constraints? In some cases, it is possible to define the augmented state $z=(x,\dot x)$, which brings your problem back to a standard optimal control problem that can be addressed e.g. using Pontryagin's maximum principle.

Comment: I have added more details related to my problem. But regardless of what dynamics is, isn't there a theorem for general case just like for standard optimal control problem for sufficient conditions for existence?

Comment: Theorems have conditions that must be satisfied to apply them. If you do not explicitly state your problem with all its details, it is more difficult to answer your questions. What is $u(t)$ in your case? It does not seem to enter the dynamics. Please make some effort to ask a clear question.

Comment: Added more details, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compute the time derivative of your state equations and use the fact that $v$ is constant, then you get

$$\ddot{x}=-v\dot{\theta}\sin(\theta),\ \ddot{y}=v\dot{\theta}\cos(\theta).$$

Your cost becomes

$$J=\int_0^1\bar{u}(t)^2v^2dt$$

with the state equations

$$\dot{x}=v\cos(\theta),\ \dot{y}=v\sin(\theta),\ \dot{\theta}=\bar u.$$

Then, it is a standard optimal control problem that can be resolved using Pontryagin's Maximum Principle. This can be found on any textbook on optimal control. Note, however, that your problem may not admit an optimal control closed-form expression.

Comment: But in this case, won't the problem change in the sense that earlier the control was the variable angle $\theta$ and now its $\dot \theta$? I mean how do I relate this new control in physical scenario?

Comment: @Phoenix8128 The control input $\theta$ is just the integral of the new control input $\bar u$. This is explicitly stated in the dynamical equation. Also, you have not stated anything regarding any physical scenario.

Comment: I know the new control is $\bar u$, that's why I said its $\dot \theta$, which is  the same. Physical scenario as in earlier the control was the velocity of the object and now its the angular velocity of the object( which was the term I was asking about). So I was concerned about this change of control from velocity to angular velocity, which effectively changes the optimal control problem. Is there no direct result for the type of cost functional I have written? Or is this the only way to proceed when the higher order state derivates are involved?

Comment: The optimal control problem is exactly the same. You compute $\bar u$ that solves the optimal control problem and then you integrate it in order to get the velocity that solves the optimal control problem. There is no general rule as to consider those costs, but when it can be brought back to a simpler problem, like here, it should be considered for simplicity.

Comment: Hey, I have one doubt related to this problem. Does showing the existence of an optimal solution of the converted problem enough to say that the original problem also has a solution as both are the same/equivalent? Is there any result saying if two optimal control problems are equivalent and we can show the existence of optimal solution of one problem, then it follows that the other equivalent problem also has an optimal solution?

Comment: @Phoenix8128 This can be checked manually. Assume that the existence of an optimal solution to one of the problem and try to show whether it also leads to an optimal solution to the other one, possibly under some conditions.

Comment: The problem is I am able to solve the original problem using some numerical method, but not the converted one and I am able to show the existence of optimal solution of the converted problem using Filippov's theorem but unable to do so for original one as in Filippov's existence theorem the Lagrangian is assumed to be of the form $F(x(t),u(t),t)$, so I cannot apply it to the original problem.

Comment: @Phoenix8128 Then, you will have to work more on it. Have you tried to show the equivalence of optimal solutions?

Comment: $@$KBS I am not sure how to show equivalence of optimal solutions.

Comment: @Phoenix8128 Just assume an optimal solution for one of the problems, and plug that in the other one to see what happens.